# Is it possible to use the IDE debugger using the Monotouch evaluation version?

Tags: .net, debugging, xamarin.ios

I have installed mono, the monotouch SDK and monodevelop. I have a sample project which I can set breakpoints on in the IDE.  However I can't find any option to run my sample program so that the breakpoints are hit and I can step through the code.  Is this functionality unavailable on the evaluation version, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Softmode debugging has been added in Monotouch 1.2
Debugging was not working in the previous versions. Make sure you have updated to the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

From the [MonoTouch home page](http://monotouch.net) (as of 11-14-2009 (that's MM-DD-YYYY for the non-'Mericans)):

> If you are evaluating MonoTouch, you can get your evaluation copy with the debugger from [our evaluation page](http://monotouch.net/DownloadTrial)

Just make sure you follow the directions for installation. The order in which you install the bits matters (Mono, MonoDevelop, and MonoTouch).

They also have [detailed instructions](http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Installation) - as of today (11-14-2009 (that's MM-DD-YYYY for the non-'Mericans)), there's a note in red at the bottom of the page indicating the importance of which version of MonoDevelop you need.

They've been moving quickly, adding features and fixing bugs. The upside to that is obvious - the downside is that you have to make sure you keep your Mono stack in sync with those advances. Fortunately, once you get used to it, it's really not bad - it becomes routine.

A lot of this stuff is beta, too, so some extra legwork is to be expected. But it's worth it - I just started playing with the debugger despite having used MT since its release. I was so used to not having it that I didn't even bother. But when I did, I was surprised because... well, because it works :)

I've had a couple problems (again: beta), but they're getting it figured out.

Hope this helps :)